# Firebase init error: "HTTP Error: 400, Invalid project ID specified"

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cli

I am trying to create a very simple chat application using progressive app dev and firebase.

I have created the Firebase project and am trying to initiate it on my cmd to the public folder of my app. However it continues to spit out Error 400.

```
 C:\Users\mycomputer\Desktop\InstantChatApp\public>firebase init

     ######## #### ########  ######## ########     ###     ######  ########
     ##        ##  ##     ## ##       ##     ##  ##   ##  ##       ##
     ######    ##  ########  ######   ########  #########  ######  ######
     ##        ##  ##    ##  ##       ##     ## ##     ##       ## ##
     ##       #### ##     ## ######## ########  ##     ##  ######  ########

You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

  C:\Users\mycomputer

Before we get started, keep in mind:

  * You are initializing in an existing Firebase project directory

? Are you ready to proceed? Yes
? Which Firebase CLI features do you want to setup for this folder? Press Space to select features, then Enter to confi
rm your choices. Database: Deploy Firebase Realtime Database Rules, Firestore: Deploy rules and create indexes for Fire
store, Functions: Configure and deploy Cloud Functions, Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites, Storage:
Deploy Cloud Storage security rules

=== Project Setup

First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add,
but for now we'll just set up a default project.

i  .firebaserc already has a default project, skipping

=== Database Setup

Firebase Realtime Database Rules allow you to define how your data should be
structured and when your data can be read from and written to.

? What file should be used for Database Rules? database.rules.json
+  Database Rules for undefined have been downloaded to database.rules.json.
Future modifications to database.rules.json will update Database Rules when you run
firebase deploy.

=== Firestore Setup

Firestore Security Rules allow you to define how and when to allow
requests. You can keep these rules in your project directory
and publish them with firebase deploy.

? What file should be used for Firestore Rules? firestore.rules

Firestore indexes allow you to perform complex queries while
maintaining performance that scales with the size of the result
set. You can keep index definitions in your project directory
and publish them with firebase deploy.

? What file should be used for Firestore indexes? firestore.indexes.json

=== Functions Setup

A functions directory will be created in your project with a Node.js
package pre-configured. Functions can be deployed with firebase deploy.


Error: HTTP Error: 400, Invalid project ID specified.
```

I have a index.html with the correctly assigned project links in the header as well as a js with the correct calls and functions and links. 
No matter what I fiddle with it ends up with the same Error: 400.

Comment: That's probably because you are initializing in an existing Firebase project directory. Try deleting your `.firebaserc` file

Comment: I  see there is such files and I have removed them. Perfect, thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 4):

The Firebase CLI will look in the current directory and all parent directories for a file called `.firebaserc` that defines which project is being used in this directory structure. If you run `firebase init` and encounter the message "You are initializing in an existing Firebase project directory", that means one of these `.firebaserc` files was found, and it's going to re-initialize the existing project.

In your specific case, it looks like the CLI encountered a `.firebaserc` file that contains the name of a project that's not valid for the account that you used when you ran `firebase login`.  Perhaps you deleted the project, or it was associated with another account.

It sounds like you were able to discover the `.firebaserc file` and delete it so that you can initialize the project correctly.